# Multi-module Maven with Profile in Eclipse Doesn't Resolve Dependencies on Children

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e, multi-module

For my setup, I have profiles defined in my `~/.m2/settings.xml`, where the profiles define some project-specific repositories. From the command line, I can successfully build the projects using `-PprofileHere`. However, the profile isn't enabled automatically (i.e. `activeByDefault` is not set to `true` for the profile).

In Eclipse 4.5.1 (Mars 1) with m2e 1.6.2.20150902-0002, I import the projects using `Import` → `Maven` → `Existing Maven Projects`. I select the parent project and Eclipse imports them. The children projects are imported, but as expected, their dependencies aren't correctly resolved. To attempt to fix this, I select the parent project, right-click `Maven` → `Select Maven Profiles...` and select the correct profile for the parent. I then do the m2e tango by trying various combinations of the following:

- Cleaning and rebuilding the project (`Project` → `Clean...`)
- Updating the parent project (Right-click, `Maven` → `Update Project...`)
- Updating the children projects (ditto)
- Restarting Eclipse

Eclipse continuously shows the dependencies unresolved on the children projects when viewing the children `pom.xml`'s or opening a class in a child module with unresolved dependencies. The *only* workaround I've found is by enabling the profile automatically in my `~/.m2/settings.xml`. Then and only then does Eclipse properly resolve the Maven dependencies.

What am I doing wrong when originally importing / configuring projects in Eclipse?

Comment: You appear to do everything right. Both Eclipse and m2e are up-to-date. Did you try to update your Maven Settings by going to Windows > Preferences > Maven > User settings" and clicking "Update settings" a couple of times and then a random combination of Apply and OK? Try to add this to your m2e dance.

Comment: Just tried @Tunaki, didn't work.

Comment: I personally have never used the "Select Maven Profiles..." feature... Maybe you just hit a m2e bug. You should try to get in touch with the m2e team.

Comment: @Tunaki Ok, seems like a bug. I'll see what the m2e team states. Hopefully it's already known...

Comment: I know it doesn't answer the question, but just wondering: why such a non-active-by-default profile then? It means your build is not fine without activating that profile, which goes a bit against maven best practices (I shouldn't know about that profile and I should be able to build it simply executing mvn clean install).

Comment: Added bug [484279](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=484279). Time will tell.

Comment: @Tunaki - turned out not to be a bug; rather it's by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How it worked for me in a sample project providing the same scenario: make Eclipse use a profile by default for a Maven build.

- Right click on the concerned project > Properties > Maven
- Type your profile there, it will be used by Eclipse during the build

[image]

I never used this option, but apparently its purpose should suit your need.

Comment: Winner, winner, chicken dinner! This also bypasses [bug 484280](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=484280).